# nth-child based in element index

Tags: css

I want to use css3 nth-child to select matched elements based in their index in the whole document (like jquery :eq() selector) not based in the parent element.

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="result">
      <div class="active">content 1</div>
   </div>

   <div class="result">
      <div class="active">content 2</div>
   </div>

   <div class="result">
      <div class="active">content 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This css code select all elements because every .active is 1st child respective to the parent .result

```
.active:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
```

I tried also to make the body as parent

```
body > .active:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
```

But it can't do the job.

I want nth-child(1) selects content 1
and nth-child(2) selects content 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use nth-child on `.result`.

```
#container .result:nth-child(1) .active {
  background: red;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gufilediya/edit?html,css,js,output)